# How to get the timestamp since midnight UT

Tags: c#, .net, timestamp, icmp

How can I convert some hex values into the timestamp **since midnight UT** from an **ICMP** packet ([reference rfc792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792)) like in wireshark:

[image]

---

I've converted the hex value `DE AD BE EF` to decimal `3735928559` and tried this to get the originate timestamp:

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3735928559);

string timestamp = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m:{2:D2}s:{3:D3}ms",
                t.Hours,
                t.Minutes,
                t.Seconds,
                t.Milliseconds);
```

But I get 05h:45m:28s:559ms instead of 18 days, 0 hours, 14 minutes and so on like in wireshark.
(I know the date format is not the same, but the value is nevertheless wrong).

Comment: `TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3735928559)` would give you 43 days, 5 hours, 45 minutes and 28 seconds. So you are not getting the proper value for milliseconds. Also you are not even displaying days in your formatted string.

Comment: `0xDEADBEEF` is usually a placeholder for no data, or means something's gone wrong.

Comment: Ok two questions: - is that still the right approach or is something wrong except the format? - and second: does anybody know where I can get a trace file with an icmp timestamp?